# How to apply Javascript on php div?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I just started learning php. I'm trying to apply very simple javascript function on a div created by php. the javascript function doesn't work at all or respond. Why?

index.php:

```
<html>
     <head>
     </head>
     <body>
          <script type = "text/javascript" src = "testing.js"></script>

          <?php
                 echo '<div id="div1"></div>';
          ?>

     </body>
</html>
```

testing.js:

```
document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML = 'Changing values'
```

Comment: Do you receive any error?

Comment: Does it work if you don't use php?

Comment: Your script tag needs to be after the div. Unless you wrap it in some kind of window.onload function

Comment: without that code being inside a load event handler the element won't be found because it doesn't exist yet when your script tag precedes the element. Put the script tag after the element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are executing the JS immediately at the time the script file is read.  You need to defer it until the page is loaded, with e.g. an onload or DOMContentLoaded event, or `$().ready` if using jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I suggest you try this if it works

```
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "testing.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML = 'Changing values';
});
</script>
```

1. First, your javascript should be outside HTML tags.
2. Second, check whether you had your script ready by testing it such as `alert("test");` to test whether it pop up alert dialog when load the page.